# I am Unable to display the graph on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

There is this project where I have to display a dynamic graph which updates automatically without refreshing the page. I was able to do this and I am currently using the buttons so that the user can manually click whatever graph he wants to look.

The problem is once I click the second button a graph is displayed, if I again click the first button it's output is not displayed. I have attached the code for your reference.

As for the java script code I have used [Canvas Js](https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/dynamic-live-line-chart/) sample code.

Here is the code which I used to represent the graphs using buttons

```
    <button id="refresh" type="button" onclick="start_p1();">Click for Process_1</button>
<div id="chartContainer1" class="w3-display-middle" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="start_p2()">Click for Process_2</button>
<div id="chartContainer2" class="w3-display-middle" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("refresh").click(function(){
        $("chartContainer1").load(" #chartContainer1");
    });
</script>
```

I even looked about reloading the div tag but it doesn't help me as expected. I would appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance..

Edit: I have included my output in the form of image so that you can understand clearly.
**My output**
[image: My output]

Comment: You are missing `#` in `$("refresh")` should be `$("#refresh")`. Same for `$("chartContainer1")`

Comment: I did that, but as you can see from the picture after I click and view the graph of the 2nd process, I would like to go back to see the first process once again by clicking the button which is not happening.

Comment: `but as you can see from the picture` what picture do you refer to?

Comment: I have added it as a hyper link in the question. But anywhere here is the image link, https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFaLU.png

Comment: Please include both click events that you refer to

Comment: Here are the set of events-->
Event 1: I click on process_1, plot is displayed
Event 2: I click on process_2, plot is displayed
Event 3: Now when I click process_1 again, the plot is not displayed. That is my issue

Here is the video link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TdRIj5embf-iwQ9v3CAl0l-yEqNJZh7k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When you open up the console (typically `ctr+shift+i` -> console), what errors, if any, are displayed?